# Javascript Event Not displaying in Chrome Developer Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have this button:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="addToCart()" onclick="step4()" class="btn btn-submit btn-block">Add to Cart</a>
```

then I have this Javascript:

```
function step4() {
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'checkout',
        'ecommerce': {
            'checkout': {
                'actionField': {'step': 4}
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In the chrome developer console, it does not show anything firing when I click the link?  Any tips?  How can I tell my JS is firing?

Comment: Events do not automatically log messages to the console, if it did your console would be overflowing with logs of mousemove and other events. If you want to log messages you have to do it yourself

Comment: Thanks Patrick.  For some reason I thought it would output on its own, but it only does that if I am debugging in Google Tag Manager (turning on debug mode makes it start displaying all the clicks and everything without making changes to the code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function should be firing, but you aren't outputting anything to the console so you won't see anything there. You should try putting a console.log() statement in your function, which will output some text to the development console.

You can do something like this, which will print to the console as soon as the function is hit, and then a second time just before it completes along with the new value of your dataLayer object:

```
function step4() {
    console.log('Inside step4 function.');

    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'checkout',
        'ecommerce': {
            'checkout': {
                'actionField': {'step': 4}
            }
        }
    });

    console.log('End of function call: ', dataLayer);
}
```

Here's a plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/fLcx1oX4Q1A6XoiBOGcp?p=preview

Comment: Yes, she works.  If you have any tips about finding the "step: 4" inside my dataLayer console output, that would be useful.  I think it is inside the 3rd object, that is where I can find the 'checkout'.

Comment: You should be able to access the properties of dataLayer using dot notation. Keep in mind your dataLayer is an array that you are pushing onto, which means you'll need to access a specific element:

`console.log('step value: ', dataLayer[0].ecommerce.checkout.actionField.step)`

Remember to check for nulls too, since if any of those properties are null or undefined you'll get an error while trying to print.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should prevent default action of anchor element

*try*
`function step4(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'checkout',
        'ecommerce': {
            'checkout': {
                'actionField': {'step': 4}
            }
        }
    });
}`

Comment: That would not help in displaying a console log message which OP is after